# Set “makeprg” via modeline in Vim

Tags: vim, makefile

By default, `makeprg` is set to just `make`. However, I’ve got a lot of projects where different build configurations and targets reside in the same directory.

This of course necessitates that I specify a target when invoking `make`.

For example, I’ve got a project that’s set up to build a source file `<foo>.cpp` by invoking `make foo`, and the project contains a number of such source files.

**How can I achieve that when I’m editing said `<foo>.cpp` in Vim, `makeprg` is set to `make <foo>`?** I thought of modelines in each file, but setting `makeprg` via the modeline is forbidden (due to security concerns?).

Notice that this setting is only appropriate for some projects so I don’t want to modify the *general* value of `make` – otherwise I’d just

```
set makeprg=make\ expand("%:t:r")
```

(or something like that) in my `.gvimrc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using a [plugin](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/misc/trunk/plugin/local_vimrc.vim) of mine that enables project-specific settings to tune that kind of things.
This way my `.vimrc` is not cluttered with project-specific things. Instead, in each project root directory I have a `_vimrc_local.vim` file that contains my various settings.

Another solution would be to encapsulate `:make` call into a another command or a mapping that in turn calls `:make` with a variable that you could set with another plugin: [let-modeline](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/misc/trunk/plugin/let-modeline.vim).

PS: the `.gvimrc` is meant to contain things specific to the graphical version of vim. By putting your settings into your `.gvimrc`, plain vim won't be configured.

Comment: re the `.gvimrc` file: of course, I’m aware of that. I’m using both, my question just wasn’t consistent. That plugin looks promising – in fact, I believe that’s exactly what I’m looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to map `:make %<` which I believe will do what you want

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to something similar with autocommands, if you can distinguish your project not by modeline but by their folder. The following is a combination of an example from `:help autocmd-patterns` and your example code.

```
:autocmd BufRead /source/foo-project/*.cpp set makeprg=make\ expand("%:t:r")
```

(Note that I haven't tested this exact command, instead I have some autocommands for setting makeprg depending on the filetype in my vimrc)

Comment: In a previous (similar, but deleted it seems) anwser, the OP said he'd rather not clutter his .vimrc with project-specific settings.